# How can I make a multi-dependent dropdown in Excel with an “If…Then” condition?

Tags: excel, drop-down-menu, excel-2010, cascadingdropdown

I am trying to do a cascading dropdown in Excel with 3 entries: Country, State and City.  I am using the name+data validation method. My problem is that most of my countries don't have a state, therefore it shows the list of cities in the state cell (because the list of cities is named "Country" and I am using "=Indirect(..)" in Data Validation). How can I include some kind of “If…Then” function stating that if there is no state, then show “N/A” in dropdown 2 and show the list of cities (named “Country”) in the third dropdown ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use a Pivot workaround or a sorted table I warmly recommend a `=OFFSET(yourrange,MATCH(lev1_match,yourrange,0)-1,1,COUNTIFS(yourrange,lev1_mat‌​ch))` function. This will match with "invalid" characters as well.
If you use the indirect function then it would be some messed up `=INDIRECT(A1 & "_" & A2)` where `A2` = "NA". The referred range would then be e.g. "Austria_NA".
Only valid characters can work this way.

Comment: The question has a false premise. You can't put a formula in a dropdown (not in the conventional sense). If you'd like to modify the cell content automatically, you'd need to resort to VBA.